# Call finish() or not?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am trying to fetch some API data to my app and I have two activities. The first one is a Splash Screen (like those used by google while your app gets loaded) and I want to know where to call finish() to end the activity.

```
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    AsyncDataFetch fetch = new AsyncDataFetch();
    fetch.setContext(this);
    fetch.execute();

}
```

}

I have moved all my code in my AsyncTask so I don't block the ui thread and now I can't call finish() there, or I don't know how.

Why would I call finish for my app there instead of calling it on my activity you might ask... It is because it generates some sort of glitch if I do this, because my API fetch takes about 1 second and showing and closing this activity takes less.

So, where should I call finish() and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call `finish()` in onPostExecute of Async Task after getting result from doInBackground().

Comment: Hi. Thank you very much. In fact, I was trying to call this as you said, but it seems that this finish () method is not recognized out of the activity. I have tried to call it from context (same as passed by setContext() method) and with SplashActivity.class.finish(). How do I call this? I haven't found relevant answers on google yet

Comment: SplashActivity.this.finish()

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If your activity you wanna finish is a splash srceen, you should put `finish()` at `postExecute()`, which should be overriden in your asyncsTask.